# A class. puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, rebus

These three parts are in correct order but can be solved independently. Two of them are initials and one is an anagram name. The answer to this puzzle is... well, you'll notice :)

Good luck!

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

For the colorblind. The colors are (row by row):

Blue, Grey, Red, Black, Green

Brown, White, Indigo, Yellow, Orange

Comment: In part 2, should the sixth icon in the list have one fewer bar around it? Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv I am highly impressed. (I'd solved 1 and got stuck on 2 in the obvious place; _with your suggested correction_ indeed 2 is clear as is what 3 must be, though I haven't yet figured out why. But since you haven't just posted an answer, it seems you figured out what 2 must be with at most one of 1,3, which I find very impressive indeed.)

Comment: (I have _a_ way to get the right thing out of 3 but I am pretty sure it's wrong because it doesn't use everything in the image.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ha, thanks :) I actually figured out 2 first, then back-solved 1! I'm stuck on 3, same as you though - although like you I'm sure I know what it *should* be...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Actually, I think I've just worked it out! EDIT: Ah, rats, actually I haven't used the arrow, which I suspect is the same as you... Darn it - I've just written it all up. Might post anyway...

Comment: I confirm that your not-entirely-satisfactory answer to 3 is the same as mine :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle is:

> **W. AMADEUS. M** - a famous *class(ical)* [composer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart).

**Puzzle 1:**

To solve this, note that FRA and GIN are:

> 3-letter country abbreviations for **France** and **Guinea**. These two countries have triband flags, France's being blue-white-red and Guinea's being red-yellow-green. If we join these coloured dots in this order, we see a '**W**' traced out:
>
>  [image]

**Puzzle 2:**

The moon and sun icons here have connotations with:

> *Monday* and *Sunday* (these days of the week are named after them). Note then that beneath these symbols we have *seven* rows of boxes. Moreover, the number of boxes in these rows correspond to the number of letters in the names of the *seven* days of the week in English.
>
>  Note next that each 'thumbs-up' bullet point is surrounded by a number of bars. Count these up and index into the corresponding day of the week to extract a letter. This yields:
>
>  **M**ONDAY, TUE**S**DAY, W**E**DNESDAY, TH**U**RSDAY, FRI**D**AY, SATURD**A**Y and SUND**A**Y.
>
>  Together, this gives the letter set MSEUDAA, which is an anagram of **AMADEUS**.
>
>  [image]

**Puzzle 3:**

This is a rebus of sorts that requires a few steps to it:

> Here, 'Pr' represents 'prime'. The 9th prime (indicated by the substring '9') is 23. The 23rd letter of the English alphabet is 'W', and rotating this 180 degrees (as suggested by the arrow) turns our 'W' into an '**M**'.
>  <sub>*This explanation clarified in comments by the OP, below, following my initial chemistry-connected suggestion neglected to use a part of the rebus.*</sub>

Comment: Aaah mistake there, it should of been seven bars ofc! As for the 3rd image, rot13 (zl vagragvba jnf gung vf ercerfragrq gur 9gu *cevzr*, juvu vf 23. Gur 23eq yrggre vf J, ebgngr 180 naq jr trg Z.)

Comment: @Primenumbah Ah, I see - I got sideswiped by chemistry again! Will amend my answer. Feel free to fix the image if you like and I'll fix up my text afterwards to match...

Comment: It's fixed now.